# Где реализован IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, коллекции

У меня появился вопрос, который не дает мне покоя вот уже несколько часов. Для того, чтобы использовать foreach для кастомной коллекции, нужно реализовать метод интерфейса IEnumerable.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(){
        return arr.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

С этим все ясно. Но какой класс реализует интерфейс **IEnumerator**? По началу я думал System.Array, но после того, как я не увидел IEnumerator в списке родителей System.Array решил обратиться сюда.

Comment: `Для того, чтобы использовать foreach для кастомной коллекции, нужно реализовать метод интерфейса IEnumerable` - неверно, достаточно наличия метода `GetEnumerator()` - имплементировать для `foreach` какой то интерфейс не обязательно.

Comment: @tym32167, да, я понимаю это. Я должен был скорее вместо «нужно», написать «можно» :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerator` реализован типом, объект которого возвращает `arr.GetEnumerator()`.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
  IEnumerator result = arr.GetEnumerator();
  Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().FullName);
  return result;
}
```

Тип возвращаемого объекта - `System.Array.SZArrayEnumerator`. Вот этот `SZArrayEnumerator` и реализует `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Лодку капитану :D

Comment: @tym32167 Не, "карету мне, карету!"

Comment: @Igor, результат — System.Array, но почему тогда System.Array не наследует IEnumerator?

Comment: @DAVIDOGANESYAN результат - `System.Array.SZArrayEnumerator`

Comment: @Igor, значит проблема в компиле) Спасибо большое!